# Combining several rows to one data range to circumvent the 1024 column restriction

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to work with a larger data set (deaths per week since 2000), exceeding the 1024 columns restriction of LibeOffice Calc.

My source has got 52 (or 53) numbers per row for each year. I'Ve manually put those in a single row for 6 years (row 3 and 4 in the picture are stretching far to the right...), which works fine. Then I can plot a diagram like this:

[image]

But it doesn't fit for 21 years, because the number of weeks exceeds 1024. I'd need to somehow add a data range to the diagram that would include 21 rows (or at least 2 large ones) with in sum more than 1024 entries, so Calc behaves like it would be a single input row for the diagram.

Comment: I don't quite understand how your data is set up. Is it by row or by column? Please edit the question to give a small example input and describe the desired result.

Comment: @JimK I hope an image says more than a thousand words... :) Also improved on the text, I hope.

Comment: I found a way to get the diagram I want: Transposing the data (https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/guide/table_rotate.html) and exchange columns and rows in the diagram. Then I can work with 2 or 3 columns and >1024 rows. Still not answering the question about data ranges using several rows, so I'll leave that open.

Answer (score 0):

The image below shows a standard LibreOffice Calc (version 6.4)
column chart generated by selecting

- the 10 rows by 54 columns data area defined in `$Sheet1.$A$4:$BB$13`
- menu: Insert | Chart ... | column chart
- in tab data range: [x] first column as label
- no legend display, Finish

plus editing following chart elements

- x-axis, positioning, select labels outside start
- y-axis, scale, set minimum and maximum

With 52 weeks in most years and 53 in the rest there will be a slight
inaccuracy in the display but it's hardly noticeable in standard
presentations and even so unlikely to disturb the message of the
illustration.

[image: su1674223.png]